# Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node. In React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add a spinner but there is a problem while executing the program

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import LoginFailModal from './LoginFailModal';

class Login extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username : "",
            password : "",
            error:false,
            loading:false
        }
    }


    inputSet =(e)=> {
     //console.log(e.target.name);
     this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    }

    loginCheck =(e)=>{
        this.setState({['error']:false});
        this.setState({['loading']:true});
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {
            emph : this.state.username,
            password : this.state.password
        };
        
        axios.post("url",data).then(response=>{
        if(response.data.status=='200')
        {   
            var response_data = response.data.data;
            var user_data = {'token':response_data.token,
                             'user_type':'staf'}
            localStorage.setItem('user_data', user_data); 

           this.setState({['error']:true,['loading']:false});
        }
        else
        {
            this.setState({['error']:true,['loading']:false});
                }

        
        })
    }

    render()
    {   
        let {loading} = this.state;
        
        return( 
        <>
        {this.state.error ? (<LoginFailModal/>):""}
        <div class="row">
                <div className="col-xl-7 col-lg-4 col-md-2">
            <img className="bg_img" src="assets/images/bg.jpg" alt=""/>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xl-5 col-lg-4 col-md-2">
            <div className="login">
            <img className="login-logo" src="assets/images/login-logo.png" alt=""/>
                
                <form className="input">
                    <input className="text-field" type="text" name="username" onChange={this.inputSet} placeholder="Username" id=""/>
                    <input className="text-field" type="password" name="password" onChange={this.inputSet} placeholder="Password" id=""/>
                    <p className="fp">Forgot Password?</p>
                
                <div className="cal">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div col-xl-4 col-lg-2 col-md-2>
                            <p className="sum">40+40</p>
                        </div>
                        <div col-xl-5 col-lg-2 col-md-2>
                            <input className="get" type="text" name="" placeholder="" id=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <p className="pl-5 remember"><input type="checkbox" name="remember me" id=""/>
                    Remember me</p>
                </div>
                <div className="login_button">
                <p style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.error}</p>
                        <button className="button" onClick={this.loginCheck}>Login 
                        &nbsp;{loading && <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin" style={{color:'white'}}></i>}</button>
                </div>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
         </>
        )
        

    }
    
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: You could format your code better.

Comment: Is encapsulating elements in an unnamed tag (<> </>) valid react syntax? Aren't you supposed to use <Fragment>?

Comment: @Ianxion .. yes, it is. Similar to Fragment.